What is the best practise to pass values between activities after using shared preferences in users authentication implementation?
I have a login-activity in my application. After successful authentication, I add user to DB and wput a unique userId to SharedPreferences to keep user logged and check it in every activity. The user navigates to the next activity where various DB queries are being executed, based on userId.
"select * from users where userId = 'userId'" or smth
My question is what is the best practise:

to use userId from Shared Preferences in every activity for DB queries

to pass userId between activities by intents
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("userId", userId)
startActivity(intent)


Thanks for your answers

neither of  them. This is not the 100% best approach, but in your case -> put the user_id in a common global place & access it wherever you need. If you want a proper solution, search "android dependency injection"

If you want to use the userId in multiple activities then you can define a class AppState like this:
data class AppState(
    val userId: Int? = null
)

then use the hilt to manage its dependency injection.
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {
    
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSharedPreferences(@ApplicationContext context: Context): SharedPreferences {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("my_app_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    }
    
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppState(pref: SharedPreferences): AppState {
        val userId: Int? = pref.getInt("user_id_key", null)
        return AppState(userId = userId)
    }
}

Your application class:
@HiltAndroidApp
class ExampleApplication : Application() { ... }

To get the userId in any activity simply inject the AppState like this:
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MyActivity : Activity() {
    
    @Inject 
    lateinit var appState: AppState 
    
    fun onSaveStudent() {
        val userId = appState.userId   // retrieve the userId from app state
    }
}

A big advantage of this approach is that we read the userId only once from the shared preferences. It can be used easily in any activity or other components by injecting the AppState. Moreover the AppState can be used to hold any application-level data that you need to share between different components of the application.
